# Reading frames from a folder and display in QGraphicsView in pyqt4

Tags: pyqt4, qgraphicsview, bounding-box

I am trying to read frame for a folder and display in QGraphics view.

```
import os
import PyQt4
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
dir = "frames"
for file in os.listdir(dir):
    grview = QtGui.QGraphicsView()
    scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
    #pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(os.path.join(dir, file))
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(file)    
    item = QtGui.QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
    self.scene.addItem(item)
    grview.setScene()    
    grview.show()
    #self.scene.update()
```

The folder named "frames" contains jpg files and is in the same folder as the code. But still I am not able to read the frames.

I have also tried general display without graphicsview to check if it works using the code below but it too doesn't work.

```
import cv2
import os
import PyQt4
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

def load_images_from_folder(folder):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename))
        if img is not None:
            images.append(img)
    return images

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)    

    img = load_images_from_folder('/frames')
    image = Image.open(img)
    image.show()
```

I am not able to understand what am I missing. I want to display the images sequentially in QGraphicsView resembling a video and in some particular frame I have to select the object of interest by draw a rectangle around it which has to hold in the subsequent frames as well. Is the task i am attempting possible? if yes any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I have PyQt5.
Try it:

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import Qt
#from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Qt.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)

        self.scene  = Qt.QGraphicsScene()
        self.grview = Qt.QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.grview)

        dir = "frames"
        self.listFiles = os.listdir(dir)

        self.timer = Qt.QTimer(self)    
        self.n = 0
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.on_timeout)
        self.timer.start(1000)

        self.setGeometry(700, 150, 300, 300)
        self.show()

    def on_timeout(self):

        if self.n < len(self.listFiles):
            self.scene.clear()
            file = self.listFiles[self.n]
            pixmap = Qt.QPixmap("frames\{}".format(file))    # !!!  "frames\{}"
            item   = Qt.QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
            self.scene.addItem(item)
            self.grview.setScene(self.scene)                 # !!! (self.scene)
            self.n += 1
        else:
            self.timer.stop()

app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
GUI = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Its working fine in PyQt4 by (a) commenting PyQt5 and un commenting PyQt4 (b) replace all "Qt." with Qt.Gui except for Qtimer where it is QtCore.Qtimer   Thanks for the help

Comment: Spoke too soon,there is a problem with the reading. In between every frame read the display is showing first frame continuously, When i changed the timing to 30ms to making the display look like a video. I later changed it back to 1000ms but still the problem is there. The display  is jerky because of this.What could be the issue?

Comment: @ S Nick:  Weird observation, If i delete initial 200 frames, it is working fine. I will get into the details and get back if any further issues. Thanks for the help

Comment: @ S Nick: I tried to do the same operation by importing the Ui from a parent Gui, but didnot work. Can you help me with the changes I need to do.